# Black Bar above navigation bar and below footer ios in iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, uinavigationbar

It's a black bar just like navigation bar but it's above my navigation bar and at the end of my screen as well. App is working fine on other devices but not on iPhone 5 
 I uploaded the image here http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=rmoj6s&s=8#.VG22QVeUewE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent added splash screen for iphone 5 so it causes black  bar above navigation and below footer add default splash and your problem will be solved